# How to create function returning value up to first non-digit/decimal charcater

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.0

val function should return numeric value from string up to first non-digit character, considering first decimal point also:

```
val('1,2TEST')  should return 1.2
val('1,2,3')  should return 1.2
val('-1,2,3')  should return -1.2
val('')  shound return 0
```

I tried

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.VAL(value text)
  RETURNS numeric AS
$BODY$
SELECT coalesce(nullif('0'||substring(Translate($1,',','.'), '^-?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$'),''),'0')::numeric;
$BODY$ language sql immutable;
```

but if string contains % character,

```
select val('1,2%')
```

returns 0.

How to force it to return 1.2 ?
It should work starting from Postgres 9

**Update**

Gordon Fiddle for 9.5 support returns null for not numeric string. I solved it using wrapper:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.VALwithNull(value text)
  RETURNS numeric AS
$BODY$
SELECT    replace( (regexp_matches($1, '^-?[0-9]+,*[0-9]*'))[1], ',', '.') ::numeric;
$BODY$ language sql immutable;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.VAL(value text)
  RETURNS numeric AS
$BODY$
SELECT coalesce( VALwithNull($1) ,0) ;
$BODY$ language sql immutable;

select  val('') , val('test'), val('-77,7%')
```

Is this best way to support 9.0+ ?

Comment: Postgres 9.0 has long been [end-of-life](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). Why do you need to support such an outdated version? (And 9.5 is going to be end-of-life in about 6 months)

Comment: 9.0 is used in number of servers. Upgrading it is too much work.

Comment: Keeping such an older server alive is much more work, but more importantly is much more risk. And the longer you wait with the (mandatory) upgrade the harder it will get.

Comment: 9.0 servers work without any work required. How it is much more work ?

Comment: You don't get any security updates so you need to invest time and money to keep it secure. Depending on the business you are running, not having security updates could mean substantial repercussions if something goes wrong. You also don't get any bugfixes for bugs that can potentially corrupt your database, which could cost you time and money if things go wrong. Are you also still using Windows XP? Or a Linux 2.4 Kernel? If you upgrade early, upgrades are typically **much** less work than if you wait 10 years or longer to do that.

Comment: @Andrus because any problems you encounter won't get any fixes. Because tools will stop working. Because when you eventually are forced to upgrade, you'll find you have no direct path to a fresh version, and have to migrate by hopping from one intermediate version to the next

Comment: @Andrus because at some point you may find you're locked into obsolete tools, stacks and providers. How long is Npgsql going to support PostgreSQL 9.0? Will their .NET 5 provider still support it? What if you get stuck in an old .NET Core version due to your obsolete database?

Comment: @Angus this isn't nitpicking either. NpgSQL had trouble connecting to Amazon's Redshift because it used an ancient PostgreSQL 8.0 API. NgpSQL tried to set certain options when opening a connection that weren't available in Redshift/PostgreSQL 8

Comment: Your question is actually another example why this is more work: you got an answer that works for the current version, now you need to find a different solution that works with unsupported versions to simulate a feature that has been integrated into Postgres some time ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this regular expression does what you want:

```
replace( (regexp_match($1, '^-?[0-9]+,*[0-9]*') )[1], ',', '.')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=60b6e02d67ea990e7778c443dca8275d) is a db<>fiddle.

You can also use `regexp_matches()`.  It does the same thing in this context.

Comment: For '-1,2TEST' fiddle return null . How to enable minus sign in start of string ?

Comment: changing version to 9.5 in Fiddle produces error. How to make it work from Postgres 9.0+ ? I updated question.

Comment: @Andrus . . . Use `regexp_matches()` instead:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=706d3bd3c621e8c14fc30f80bac71af9.

Comment: How to force it return 0 if string does not start with number? I tried `select coalesce( replace((regexp_matches(str, '^[0-9]+,*[0-9]*'))[1], ',', '.'), '0')
from (values ('T'),('')) v(str)` but got error `set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set`

Comment: @Andrus . . . This answers the question you have asked here.  If you have a different question, ask as a *new* question.

Comment: I converted null to 0 using wrapper function in updated part of question. Is this best way to supprt 9.0+?

Comment: @Andrus . . . Oh, if you just want to convert `NULL` to `0`, use `coalesce()`:  `coalesce(replace(regexp_match($1, '^-?[0-9]+,*[0-9]*'))[1], ',', '.'), '0')`.

Comment: This throws error `ERROR: syntax error at or near "["` . Looks like it is not supported in 9.4

Comment: @Andrus . . . `regexp_matches()` is in Postgres 9.4.

Comment: `regexp_matches()` worked in 9.4 as shown in question update. It looks like array indexer `[1]` causes error in 9.4 . Is using wrapper function as shown in question update best way to solve this ?

Comment: @Andrus . . . There was a missing opening paren.  It should not have worked in any version.  The code is correct in the dbfiddle . . . and here is a db<>fiddle showing that it works in 9.4:  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cygpqfJZQTUPxK4XT4cnyT/0.

Comment: In  9.4 fiddle `select coalesce( replace((regexp_matches(x, '^-?[0-9]+,*[0-9]*'))[1], ',', '.'), '0' )  from (values ('TEST')) v(x)` still returns `error: set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set`. How to return 0 if string does not start with digit and - sign?